# Need to design classes in typescript for highly nested objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, oop

So i have model classes to create objects, basically i want to achieve is to create dynamic objects this way. But I do not think this is a good way, can someone help me with this? How can i make this cleaner and more readable. This is a trial to create nested json objects to be sent for a request.

```
return new ClassBase(
new ClassA(
new ClassB(
iAuthPassword,
),
new ClassC(name),
),
new ClassD(sessionToken),
new ClassE(
new ClassF(['ABC', 'DDA']),
),
);
```

Comment: Don't use classes for this, use plain objects instead whenever possible.

Comment: but i am modeling everything in classes

Comment: It's up to you, but IMO it's a mistake. JS (and TypeScript in particular) is more suited for a functional style I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd use a plain [object literal](https://javascript.info/object#literals-and-properties):

```
let request = {
  credentials: {
    password: iAuthPassword,
  },
  name,
  sessionToken,
  list: ['ABC', 'DDA']
};
```

If this is your only use of that type, I see no benefit in declaring a separate type for this. If you do need the type elsewhere in your code, I'd declare an interface:

```
interface AuthRequest {
  credentials: {
    password: string,
  },
  name: string,
  sessionToken: string,
  list: string[];
}
```

In either case, you can declare nested types by nesting the types. This has the advantage that the nesting is obvious in the source code and you don't have to name the inner types (unless you want to, for instance to reuse them elsewhere).

Using classes to describe JSON is not usually a good idea, because the sole advantage of classes is that they have a prototype for inheriting state of behavior, which is not usually needed for objects whose sole purpose is being turned into JSON.